# How to update the values of partitioned columns in Delta?

Tags: delta-lake

I wanted to know, whether is it possible to update the "values"  of column on which the delta table is partitioned?

The table is partitioned on a particular column, now I want to update the value of that particular column. Can I do that?

---

(found on [slack](https://delta-users.slack.com/archives/CJ70UCSHM/p1578314425085300))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replaceWhere` option.

Quoting the official documentation at [Replace table schema](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#replace-table-schema):

> By default, overwriting the data in a table does not overwrite the schema. When overwriting a table using `mode("overwrite")` without `replaceWhere`, you may still want to overwrite the schema of the data being written. You replace the schema and partitioning of the table by setting the `overwriteSchema` option to `true`.

Quoting the article [Selectively updating Delta partitions with replaceWhere](https://mungingdata.com/delta-lake/updating-partitions-with-replacewhere/):

> Delta makes it easy to update certain disk partitions with the `replaceWhere` option.
>
> `replaceWhere` is particularly useful when you have to run a computationally expensive algorithm, but only on certain partitions.